# Proof that $t^ne^{-t}\leq Ce^{-t/2}$ for all $n\geq 1$ and $t\geq 0$

Tags: calculus, analysis

How do I prove that $t^ne^{-t}\leq Ce^{-t/2}$ for all $n\geq 1$ and $t\geq 0$. I am not sure which type of proof to use, for example induction with two variables. The graphs suggest C can always be found.

Comment: This needs quantifiers. Are you wanting to prove that $$\exists C\in \mathbb R\forall t\ge 0\forall n\ge 1(t^ne^{-t}\leq Ce^{-t/2})?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all $n\ge 1$ the function
$$f_n\colon t\mapsto t^ne^{-t/2}$$
is continuous and has the limit $0$ at $\infty$ so the function is bounded by say $C_n$. Moreover,
$$f'_n(t)=t^{n-1}\left(n-\frac t2\right)e^{-t/2}=0\iff t=2n$$
hence we see that 
$$\sup_{t\in [0,\infty)}f_n(t)=f_n(2n)=(2n)^ne^{-n}$$
and since the last sequence isn't bounded then $C_n$ isn't bounded.

Comment: You effectively spoiled all my hints =/

Comment: Is that the holiday is over? I do not see Bugs Bunny with its carrot=P

Answer (score 2):

Such an uniform bound is impossible (Look at the maxima of $t^ne^{-t/2}$ for each $n$; and that of $e^{-t/2}$). What can be claimed is that for each $n$ there exists $C_n$ such that for $t$ large enough, that happens. Indeed, since $t^ne^{-t/2}\to 0$ as $t\to +\infty$, given $\varepsilon=1$ there exists $t_0$ such that if $t\geqslant t_0$...?